# Overriding specific resource in REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a particular scenario where I have a rest resource having some methods with their path.
My requirement is to create a new resource which will extend the above resource and I want to override only a specific method and want to call rest methods from the parent API only.

For example -

```
@Path("/data")
public class AResource {
  
  @GET
  @Path("/login")
  public Response login()
  {
   //login code
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/logout")
  public Response logout()
  {
   //logout code
  }

}
```

```
@Path("/data")
public class BResource extends AResource {
  
  @GET
  @Path("/login")
  @Override
  public Response login()
  {
   //login code modified as per requirement
  }
}
```

I tried this, But its still calling parent class methods only for both the methods.

Is there any alternative to this, please suggest.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am surprised that it is not throwing any exception. You can not override them. You may workaround by delegating the call or maybe add request param. But you can't and shouldn't override the mapping.

Comment: You will get ambiguous mapping error if you do this. As rest is resources (url) based and not java method based.

Comment: I am only registering Resouce B to my server, thus its not ambiguous mapping but by default methods get executed from resource A